# What is the best way to get the following data into long format using column labels?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a nifty way of getting data into long format using column labels as follows

[image]

Into this

[image]

Comment: The function [melted](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt) will put age01, age02, ... in a single 'age' columns. You then need to convert age01 to 1.0, age02 to 2.0 etc. Alternatively try [wide_to_long](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html#reshaping-by-melt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution in numpy:

```
arr = np.array([[1., 0., 0.], [1., 0., 0.], [0., 0.,1.], [0.,1.,0.]])
names = ['age01', 'age02', 'age03']
val = [float(names[ind][4:6]) for ind in np.where(arr == 1.)[1]]
```